# SceneKit Swift 3 Inheritance does not work

Tags: inheritance, compiler-errors, 3d, swift3, scenekit

I wrote a class:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class Scene: SCNScene {

var _sceneView: SCNView!
var cameraNode: SCNNode!

func setupView(view: SCNView) {

    _sceneView = view

   }
}
```

But when I'm calling functions of that class in GameViewController:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

var scene: Scene?                       = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

    //Super
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scene = Scene()

    let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView

    ...

    sceneView.scene = scene?.setupView(view: sceneView)
  }
}
```

it shows error:

**Cannot assign value of type '()?' to type 'SCNScene?'**

And when i trying to call function it crossed-out function:

[image: crossed-out function]

Please explain and help to fix that problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function `setupView(view:)` returns `Void`. So you're trying to do `sceneView.scene = Void` which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring other potential problems (don't force unwrap (`!`) things unless you absolutely need to, underscore variable names is a convention from objective-c ivars and sometimes used for naming private storage for swift classes), what you probably want is something along the lines of:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import SceneKit
import QuartzCore
import SpriteKit

class Scene: SCNScene {

    var _sceneView: SCNView!
    var cameraNode: SCNNode!

    func setupView(view: SCNView) {

        _sceneView = view

    }
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

    var scene: Scene? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = Scene()

        let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        scene.setupView(view: sceneView)
        sceneView.scene = scene

        self.scene = scene
    }
}
```